# Rust Diesel sql_query Insert example with Returning

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to make an insert using Diesel sql_query and return the id of the inserted record, but I am getting an error

here my code

```
let demo_id: Vec<i32> = sql_query("insert into demo (demoname, description, demovalue) values (?, ?, 2) returning demoid")            
            .bind::<Text, _>("Demo1")
            .bind::<Text, _>("Demo2")
            .get_results(&conn).unwrap();
```

Getting error

```
the trait `QueryableByName<Pg>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the documentation for [`sql_query`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/fn.sql_query.html):

> Unlike most queries in Diesel, sql_query will deserialize its data by
> name, not by index. That means that you cannot deserialize into a
> tuple, and structs which you deserialize from this function will need
> to have #[derive(QueryableByName)]

So, you would have to create a struct for the data to be deserialized into:

```rust
#[derive(QueryableByName)]
struct InsertedRowId {
    #[sql_type = "Integer"]
    demoid: i32
}

// Then:

let demo_id: Vec<InsertedRowId> = sql_query("insert into demo (demoname, description, demovalue) values ($1, $2, 2) returning demoid")            
            .bind::<Text, _>("Demo1")
            .bind::<Text, _>("Demo2")
            .get_results(&conn).unwrap();
```

Note that it is important for the name of the returned column in the query to have the same name as the corresponding struct field.

See also the documentation for [`QueryableByName`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.QueryableByName.html).

Finally - note that for postgresql, placeholders in queries are specified using the syntax `$1`, `$2`, etc

Comment: thanks,  that almost work, you only have to add the sql type to the struct
#[derive(QueryableByName)]
struct InsertedRowId {
 #[sql_type = "Integer"]
    demoid: i32
}
Now I have it working :), pls update answer and I will marked as correct,

Comment: @Gonzalo Answer Updated.

Comment: Also found out that for postgres is not ? but $1, $2 in the sql statement