# Rust Diesel sql_query

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

I have a problem with diesel with SQLite where I can't use sql_query and get the inserted row.

## Code

```
   let conn = &mut get_connection();

    let new_post = NewPost{title,body};
    diesel::insert_into(posts::table)
    .values(new_post)
    .execute(conn);

    // Get the ID of the last inserted row
    let result = diesel::sql_query("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
    .load(conn);
```

## Error

```
type annotations needed
cannot infer type of the type parameter `U` declared on the associated function `load`
```

In the Example there is no Generic U used but i also tried it with **::**
which has the Error:

```
the trait bound `Untyped: load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<diesel::sql_types::Integer, _>` is not satisfied
the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>` is implemented for `Untyped`
required for `SqlQuery` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, diesel::sql_types::Integer>`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
crud.rs(29, 6): required by a bound introduced by this call
mod.rs(1499, 15): required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
the trait bound `diesel::sql_types::Integer: FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
  <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
and 23 others
required for `SqlQuery` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, diesel::sql_types::Integer>`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
crud.rs(29, 6): required by a bound introduced by this call
mod.rs(1499, 15): required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
```

Also for get Result i got the Struct:

## Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["sqlite"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
libsqlite3-sys = "0.25.2"
mysqlclient-sys = "0.2.5"
serde = "1.0.140"
```

I also tried:

```
- get by get_result with the insert which seems not to work with SQLite in this diesel Version.
- table.order(id.desc()).first(&conn) which I can't used cause i got no AUTOINCREMENT id.
- .load::<i32>
- .load::<BigInt>
```

## Artikels I already tried

- https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/771
- [How to get the id of a newly-created value with Diesel and SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437001/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-newly-created-value-with-diesel-and-sqlite) where by the way no_sql_function seems to be deprecated.
- [Rust Diesel sql_query Insert example with Returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023458/rust-diesel-sql-query-insert-example-with-returning)
  which isn't the same Problem because i just try to use sqlquery with Integer

## Question

Can someone give me a proper Example how to get the inserted Row in SQLite or explain how to solve the Error above

Comment: Your error message looks like all you need is to tell the `load` method what type to expect. I think `let result = diesel::sql_query("SELECT last_insert_rowid()").load::<i64>(conn);` should work. Then `result` will be a `QueryResult<Vec<i64>>` where the vector has one element. Read more about `load` here: https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/prelude/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.load

Comment: Hallo, thanks for the quick response!
I already tried to fill the generic type which leads to the error below.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several things to write here:

First of all the answer to the actual concrete issue. As already written in a comment below your question: You need to specify the target type for `.load()` via `.load::<TargetType>()`. In contrast what was written in this comment, you cannot use `i64` there. The documentation of [`sql_query`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/fn.sql_query.html) that the target type needs to implement `QueryableByName`. That's [not the case](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/prelude/trait.QueryableByName.html#foreign-impls) for `i64`. You need to use a struct deriving `QueryableByName` there. That should solve the concrete presented issue.

Now as the OP already mentioned: There are other solutions to make this work. As already linked you could extend the dsl to define your own `last_inserted_row`. As you noticed: `no_arg_sql_function!` as deprecated, but the [documentation](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/macro.no_arg_sql_function.html) also mentions that you just can use [`sql_function!`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/expression/functions/macro.sql_function.html#sql-functions-without-arguments) instead.

The other variant is to use support for returning clauses. That's there in diesel 2.0, [behind a feature flag](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/index.html#crate-feature-flags). As soon as you enable the corresponding feature flag + use at least sqlite 3.35 you should be able to use `get_result()` on your insert statement.